# Will same files have same hashes when uploaded from different devices?

Tags: php, file

Let's say I use this php function hash_file to get the hash of a particular file during upload.

Then that same file uploaded was printed out and then scanned in another device and upload on same server to get hash...

Will the hash of the scanned be the same as the original uploaded or different since they are uploaded from different platform but same file?